# Matching similar values in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have DataFrame in the following form:

```
Name    Count
Car     500
Cars    300
Train   100
trainz  200
Planes  1000
Plane   100 
planses 1
Ship    100
ships   10
```

I'm trying to match the similar values with eachother so that the number in `count` column is summed for similar values.

Therefore the output dataframe would be the first found  value of the given type in `name` column and summed value over all similar values in `count` column.

```
Name  Count
Car    800
Train  300
Planes 1101
Ship   110
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "similar"?

Comment: Most similar values to each other, for example `Car` is more similar to `Cars` than to `Planes`.

Comment: I don't think this will be reasonably achievable with just pandas. If this we're me, I'd use a fuzzy string matching library like [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) and set a threshold using the fuzz method. Or maybe tonekize with NLTK, but i think fuzz is your best bet if the patterns are unpredictable.

Comment: How are these data coming through to the DataFrame? I might even consider cleaning up the data before passing into the frame.  As @BrianJoseph mentioned it is not practical to do this with pandas as you'll need simple and clear definitions of the groupings before you do any sort of matching, otherwise some sort of NLP library would probably be best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html).

The following code

```
import difflib
print(difflib.get_close_matches('Car', ['Car', 'Cars', 'Train', 'trainz', 'Planes', 'Plane', 'planses', 'Ship', 'ships']))
print(difflib.get_close_matches('Train', ['Car', 'Cars', 'Train', 'trainz', 'Planes', 'Plane', 'planses', 'Ship', 'ships']))
print(difflib.get_close_matches('Planes', ['Car', 'Cars', 'Train', 'trainz', 'Planes', 'Plane', 'planses', 'Ship', 'ships']))
print(difflib.get_close_matches('Ship', ['Car', 'Cars', 'Train', 'trainz', 'Planes', 'Plane', 'planses', 'Ship', 'ships']))
```

gives your desired groups

```
['Car', 'Cars']
['Train', 'trainz']
['Planes', 'Plane', 'planses']
['Ship', 'ships']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a *custom function* (maybe use [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) from other answer...) to transform the values in `Name` to the initial similar value (if exists), and you can [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html#pandas.DataFrame.apply) to the column `Name`.

Finally, you can use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on `Name` with `sum`:

```
df.groupby('Name').agg('sum')
```

Alternative: with *apply*, create another numeric column, with same number for similar terms, then use *groupby* on the new column.